# .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce cookies cause "Nginx Request Header Or Cookie Too Large" over http

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, cookies, openid-connect

When communications happen over http, OpenIdConnect Nonce and Correlation cookies are not removed after successful authentication and it will cause `Nginx Request Header Or Cookie Too Large` error.

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` `Version=3.1` is used for the web application authentication. After first login, the user will be challenged every time they want to switch between some services. By every re-authentication, two new Nonce and Correlation cookies will be generated. If the communications happen over http, these cookies will not be removed after successful authentication until they got expired (15 mins). If the user keeps switching between services in this period, the app will fail for them with`Nginx Request Header Or Cookie Too Large` error.

For an almost similar issue in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`, there has been some solutions like [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1124#issuecomment-86631142) but I couldn't implement it since my app is using AspNetCore OpenIdConnect version 3.1.

How can I implement similar solution in AspNetCore to remove the old nonce/correlation cookies?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there was some misconfiguration on OpenIdConnnect options. The problem was that the try to remove cookies was failing because of missing "secure" flag. After setting the SecurePolicy to Always for Nonce and Correlation cookies, they were removed successfully.

```
...

options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

...
```